# Радио-кнопки в ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, expandablelistview

У меня есть ExpandableList view, пытаюсь сделать, чтобы некоторые потомки были с радио-кнопками(т.е. идут подряд с радио кнопками и при нажатии на одного потомка, радио кнопка с другого исчезает) и с чекбоксами. Пока нахожусь на стадии, где у нужных потомков стоят радио-кнопки, но они никак не зависимы друг от друга ( т.е. одновременно у нескольких потомков может быть чекнута кнопка). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добиться желаемой цели

```
 if(rad_group.equals("rg1")) {

        rbut.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (rbut.isChecked()) {
                    mSelectedChildPosition = childPosition;
                    mSelectedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
            }
            }
        });


        if (mSelectedChildPosition != childPosition && mSelectedGroupPosition != groupPosition) {
            rbut.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            rbut.setChecked(true);
            if (mSelectedRB != null && rbut != mSelectedRB) {
                mSelectedRB = rbut;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: По изменению *чекнутости* радиокнопки, записываете в переменную, у какого потомка чекнута радиокнопка, и вызывайте у `ExpandableList` notifyDatasetChanged(). Это заставит обновиться все элементы списка. А в `getChildView/getGroupView` проверяйте, какая радиокнопка должна быть чекнута, и делайте не чекнутыми все остальные

Comment: А как записать в переменную, у какого потомка чекнута радиокнопка? Я пытался "запоминать", какая кнопка чекнута , пр примеру http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter - от автора inistel . Но у меня так и не вышло ничего

Comment: да, так и надо. Если у вас не вышло, значит что-то вы сделали не правильно. Нужно в `OnCheckedChangeListener` запоминать group position И child position.

Comment: То есть вставить данный код в getChildView ( с изменением того, что не просто mSelectedPosition, а mSelectedChildPosition и mSelectedGroupPosition), а в onChildClickListener записывать в эти переменные позицию нажатого потомка, да? Правильно понимаю?

Comment: Обновил код, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: почти правильно, но вместо `OnClickListener` надо использовать `OnCheckedChangeListener`

Answer (score 1):

почти правильно, но вместо `OnClickListener` надо использовать `OnCheckedChangeListener`

```
rbut.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            mSelectedChildPosition = childPosition;
            mSelectedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
            notifyDatasetChanged();//вот эту строчку
        }

});
```

---

Прошу прощения, немного неправильно сначала написал.
Вставить это вместо `rbut.setOnClickListener(...);`

Comment: извините, но туплю..это куда вставить?

Comment: это добавил, а весь остальной код оставить прежним?

Comment: Еще одну строчку надо добавить, смотрите ответ

Comment: обновил код сверху. К сожалению, по прежнему не работает и выдает ошибку при нажатии на потомка. Данный код выше я добавлял в getChidiView, может надо еще что-то в onChildClickLIstener добавлять?

Comment: @userpixel  простите, но "не работает и выдает ошибку" достойно ответа "значит вы сделали что-то неправильно. Исправьте что-то, и заработает". Как именно *не работает*, и какую именно ошибку выдает?

Comment: Unfortunately app has stopped. И в logcat нет ошибок, почему-то

Comment: `И в logcat нет ошибок, почему-то` - Такое невозможно.

Comment: возможно дело в кнопке mSelectedRB. Она должна быть в xml файле?

Comment: проинициализировал mSelectedRB так же, как и rbut. Теперь ошибку не выдает, но при нажатии на потомка кнопка не чекается, просто остается пустой.

Comment: Нет никаких идей? Я уже замучался :(

Comment: @userpixel, Ну посмотрите в дебагере, что происходит

Comment: у меня назрело несколько вопросов, если вас не затруднит ответить : как инициализировать mSelectedRB и если мы вставляем данный код в getChildView ,  в onChildClickListener уже не надо ведь ничего про смену состояний радио кнопок добавлять?

Comment: @userpixel, задайте новый вопрос. Этот форум нацелен нестолько помочь лично вам, сколько помочь тем, у кого возникнут подобные вопросы. Если я отвечу вам сюда, в комментарий, то это будет бесполезно для всех, кроме вас.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.